# When a variable is passed to a function, what actually gets passed?

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I was told on another thread that after the function exits, any modifications made to its operands from within the function will persist.  I always thought that it made a temporary copy of all the values passed into it, and then the only things that persisted were return values and implicitly more broadly scoped variables that were modified.

I suppose thinking back to all the jquery plugins whose source code I've peaked at, they all use the construct:

```
(function($){
  $.fn.foo = function(){ console.log('foo'); };
})(jQuery);
```

which imply that modifications to the `jQuery` object even by the internal-scope `$` identifier persist after the function exits, or the jQuery plugins would not work.  So, this works as the above snippet does:

```
var x = {n:0};

(function addOneTo(p) {
  p.n = p.n + 1;
})(x);

console.log(x);
```

But this:

```
var x = 0;

(function addOneTo(p) {
  p = p + 1;
})(x);

console.log(x);
```

doesn't, leaving `x` unmodified with a value of `0`.

Could someone just explain how argument passing works? I thought I knew how it did, but I guess I don't. Thanks

Comment: The content pointed to by the variable.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that, please?

Comment: Full elaboration as an answer, bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually in your first example

```
var x = {n:0};
(function addOneTo(p) {
    p.n = p.n + 1;
})(x);
console.log(x);
```

The `x` is an object and when you used `p.n = p.n + 1;` it modified the original object's property because it passed as a reference (p is the same object as x) but in your second example

```
var x = 0;
(function addOneTo(p) {
    p = p + 1;
})(x);
console.log(x);
```

`x` is passed by a value in to the function and `p = p + 1;` here `p` is a new private variable inside that function and it has only the function scope.

Comment: So does it just matter whether the parameter is a primitive compound or value? I mean what determines whether the argument gets passed by value or reference?

Comment: Basically objects are passed by reference in javascript.

Comment: WHY so inconsistent and idiomatic?

Comment: No, no, no, it's *not* pass-by-reference. Otherwise, `p = p + 1` would change the original reference of the object `x`. JavaScript *always* uses pass-by-value, but when you have an object, you pass the *value* of the reference, not the reference itself.

Comment: In the second example `var x = 0;`

Comment: @adlwalrus: As Joao said, it's always pass-by-value and it's the same as in other languages (e.g. Java, Python).

Answer (score 1):

When you have:

```
p.n = p.n + 1;
```

What you are doing is **modifying** a property called `n` in the object **referred** to by `p`. In other words, `p` can be seen as a pointer to an object, that is, it holds a **reference** to the original object whose reference value you have passed to the function. On other hand, when you have:

```
p = p + 1;
```

You are simply **replacing** the object reference value held by `p` with the result of evaluating the expression `p + 1`. You are **not** modifying any property of the `p` object.

Comment: How am I declaring a variable? Doesn't variable declaration require the use of the `var` keyword?  If there isn't a `var` on the line, then wouldn't it traverse up to broader scopes to find one to modify until it hit `window`, at which point if it couldn't find a `p`, it would declare a new one? In my case, I would think that `p` was declared by the line `(function addOneTo(**p**) {`

Comment: Actually, not `declaring`a variable - but creating a new instance on the right side of `=` and assigning this new value to the variable `p` (whose declaration does not need the `var` keyword at all - this being one odff the major inconsistencies in javascript's syntax). Your "p" variable is declared as local in the moment it shows up in the parameter list for the inner scopped function

Comment: So could I be said to be **replacing** the property `n` of the object `p` with `p.n = p.n + 1` in the same way that I'd be replacing the value held by the variable `p` altogether with the statement `p = p + 1`?

Comment: Yes, but it's a bit misleading. Because when you change the property `n` of the object `p`, you are actually changing the original `n` property of the `x` object, whereas `p = p + 1` doesn't change the reference of the `x` object. Why? Because you did not actually pass a reference, but the reference's *value*.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually very simple: every name in Javascript points to an object in memory (even if you don't think of it in an object oriented way)-  it is a position in memory where the data structure for that "element" is.

So, if the passed value is an object like an array, or other element that has attributes and names, what you get inside the function is the same object. If you change it's attributes (like in the `p.n = p.n + 1` example above), since the "p" object is the same inside and ouside the function.

Now, when you do: `p = p + 1`, your original object, referenced by the name `p` is replaced for another object - one that is created in the expression, and which has the value of  `p + 1`. The name `p` inside the function points to another object, in another memory location entirely, and the original one, passed to the function, and reference out of it with the name `x` is left untouched.

This mechanism is exactly the same that happens in the Python language, for example.

Comment: Seems very badly designed! Could they make it any more confusing?  Why would it be so inconsistent and idiomatic?

Comment: It is rather consistent once you get the feel of it - just go to an interactive prompt (tehre are some around, or use Python) - and you will check. It is the same as in C: when you pass a structure to your function, you normally pass a pointer to the structure - if any component in the structure is modified, it is modified outside the func. If you create a new structure of the same type inside the functions, contents outside remain the same. In highe level languages, almost all elements (objects) are represented in memory as data structures (more or less complex, depending on the element)